# Para que sirven los parentesis en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

`const jsx = (<h1>Hola!</h1>);`
  El contenido de la constante es simplemente texto? que representa los parentesis que lo envuelve?
**Gracias de antemano!**

Comment: Trata por favor de dar mas contexto en tu pregunta, checa [ask]

Comment: Ok, soy nuevo en esto xd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puede que parezca una pregunta sin sentido, pero tiene un buen argumento, es decir, alguien alguna vez se ha preguntado para que pueden servirnos los paréntesis en un lenguaje de programación??, generalicemoslo, puesto que esto no es solo importante en javascript, sino en cualquier lenguaje de programacion y ademas es aplicable de la misma manera en la mayoria de estos.

Ahora bien, esto que tienes aquí:

```js
const jsx = (<h1>Hola!</h1>);
```

Definitivamente esta mal, es decir, aquello que tienes ahí no es algo que automáticamente los paréntesis lo "rendericen", puesto que eso que tienes en javascript es **totalmente invalido y va a fallar**.

Ademas tener en cuenta que aquello que tienes ahí es un mal "ejemplo de uso" de los paréntesis, puesto que enrealidad lo único que están haciendo ahí los parentesis dentro de tu código es:

**absolutamente nada.**

Debes entender que los parentesis no son "magicos", es decir, ellos no te van a "convertir" automaticamente lo que tienes ahi a algo renderizable por javascript, si deseas que ese contenido pueda ser renderizable y no muestre error, nisiquiera necesitas usar parentesis, solo debes colocar el contenido de tu constante dentro de `" "` para que se comporte como una cadena de texto de esta manera:

```js
const jsx = "<h1>Hola!</h1>";
console.log(jsx);
```

Como vemos ahora no nos da un error, pero tampoco le hemos dicho que se renderice en el documento, por lo cual vemos el resultado "literal".

Ahora bien, respecto a la pregunta de `para que sirven los paréntesis en javascript`, esto es aplicable a casi cualquier otro lenguaje de programación, y es que los paréntesis tienen diferentes utilidades, aquí describo alguna de ellas:

- Agrupar código para ser ejecutado en un orden especifico.
- Decirle al lenguaje que deberá usar el resultado de una operación agrupada por otras solo cuando esta haya finalizado de realizar sus procesos y convertirse en cierto valor.
- Funcionan cómo los parentesis en la vida real en matemáticas (para operaciones matemáticas, aquello que este dentro de paréntesis siempre sera ejecutado primero).

Vamos a hacer un ejemplo de cada punto para entenderlo mejor, para el **primer y segundo caso** tenemos el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
function dameUnRandom(num){
  return Math.random() * num;
}

const random = dameUnRandom(26) / (" " + 4);
console.log(random);
```

Esto funciona correctamente porque tenemos parentesis (estamos dándole un orden a nuestro codigo), donde le decimos primero que concantene una cadena con un espacio y luego un numero, luego, que obtengamos nuestro numero aleatorio y que nos de el resultado de la operación entre dividir nuestro nuevo numero aleatorio y el resultado de concatenar `" "` con `4`.

**Aqui el orden importa**, puesto que si lo hubiésemos hecho sin paréntesis hubiese pasado esto:

```js
function dameUnRandom(num){
  return Math.random() * num;
}

const random = dameUnRandom(26) / " " + 4;
console.log(random);
```

Lo cual supongo no es o no seria el resultado que esperas.

En el **tercer caso** podemos tener operaciones matemáticas, donde según el orden en que se hagan las operaciones podemos obtener un resultado u otro.

Veamoslo con una formula muy muy conocida, la formula de `distancia entre dos puntos`:

```js
//Intencionalmente no se usa Math.pow
function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  return Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) ** 2) + ((y2 - y1) ** 2));
}

const distanceBetweenPoints = distance(2, 4, 3, 6);
console.log(distanceBetweenPoints);
```

Pero que pasa si le quitamos todos los paréntesis exceptuando los de la función `Math.sqrt`??

```js
//Intencionalmente no se usa Math.pow
function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  return Math.sqrt(x2 - x1 ** 2 + y2 - y1 ** 2);
}

const distanceBetweenPoints = distance(2, 4, 3, 6);
console.log(distanceBetweenPoints);
```

El resultado definitivamente no es el mismo, ahora es un `NaN`, por lo cual **el orden de las cosas si importa aqui**.

**Conclusion**

Los paréntesis ayudan a **redefinir**, **aclararle** o **restringirle** al lenguaje el orden natural del como deben ocurrir las cosas o en que orden deben ser calculadas.

- Orden de ejecucion
- Orden de prioridad
- Prioridad de signos y operaciones natural
- Redefinicion de orden y prioridad

Comment: Impresionante! Te agradezco muchisimo que te hayas tomado el tiempo para responderme con tanta claridad, soy nuevo en esta comunidad la verdad nose como podria hacerte una escultura en mi perfil algo asi, te lo mereces.

Comment: por otro lado creo que lo de guardar elementos en constantes si es posible , de hecho esta en la documentación oficial (https://es.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Comment: Nuevamente muchas gracias!

Comment: fué un error de mi parte no mencionar reactjs