# Diferencia entre usar {} o () en el return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Cuál es la diferencia entre usar cada uno en React y/o JavaScript? Gracias

```
const ejemplo1 = () => {
  return ()
};

const ejemplo2 = () => {
  return {}
};
```

Comment: el return especifica lo que será devuelto por la función, si haces `return ()` estas retornando algo de forma agrupada , y al hacer `return {}` retornas un objeto

Comment: @Christian creo que debería estar como respuesta y no como comentario. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Extenderé un poco más lo que dije en mi comentario.

Al hacer un `return ()` no estas retornando nada e incluso es una sintaxis inválida, si coclocaras algo estarías retornando datos de forma agrupada, puedes saber un poco más en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/356102/183782)

Al hacer `return {}` estarías retornando un objeto vacío.

```js
function test(){
  return {};
}

console.log(test())
```

Aquí quiero destacar algo de las funciones. En caso de omitir la sentencia `return` hay un *return implícito* que es lo mismo que poner `return` a secas y esto devuelve un `undefined`.

```js
function test1(){
  let saludo = "hola";
}

function test2(){
  return;
}

console.log(test1())
console.log(test2())
```

Así que toda función tiene un `return` incluido y en todos los casos se retorna algo, ya sea algo que hayas especificado o no.