# Como manipular arreglo con paréntesis

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
const data = [(18, 20), (45, 2), (61, 12), (37, 6), (21, 21), (78, 9)]
```

El lado izquierdo de la coma dentro del paréntesis es un dato y el derecho, otro dato. El problema es que no puedo obtener el lado izquierdo, solo el lado derecho utilizando:

```
console.log(data)
```

o

```
data.map( n => n)
```

De que manera puedo manipular el arreglo para obtener el lado izquierdo también? Nunca había visto un arreglo que sus elementos sean paréntesis.

Comment: Quiero compartir esto porque la repuesta ayuda 
 a entender que hacen los parentesis en javascript https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/356089/para-que-sirven-los-parentesis-en-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El parénesis está haciendo una evaluación de lo que está dentro, la coma dentro del paréntesis lo que hace es "ejecutar" todo y devolver lo último:

```js
let variable = "valor inicial";

const data = (variable = "otro valor asignado a variable", "el valor de data");

console.log(variable);

console.log(data);
```

Se evalua en la misma creación de la variable, en este caso `data`, una vez creada no es posible acceder a los valores porque ya fue evaluada la expresión de cada paréntesis.

Otra prueba de concepto:

```js
const data = (alert("ejecuta alert"),          // <-- primero evalua todo, luego retorna el último
              console.log(esto_lanza_exepcion), // <-- Hay una exepción pero el alert lo hace
              "valor");

console.log(data);
```